# Not getting a proper fit

Tags: python

Getting an error of "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1". I am a newbie. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
def logistic(x, l, k, x1):
    return l / 1+np.exp(-k*(x-x1))
distance= [1.000*70, 2.000*70, 3.000*70, 4.000*70, 5.000*70, 6.000*70, 7.000*70, 8.000*70,
           9.000*70, 11.00*70, 12.000*70, 13.000*70, 14.000*70, 15.000*70, 16.000*70,
           17.000*70, 18.000*70, 19.000*70, 21.000*70, 22.000*70, 23.000*70, 24.000*70, 25.000*70, 26.000*70,
           27.000*70, 28.000*70, 29.000*70, 30.000*70, 31.000*70, 32.000*70, 33.000*70,
           34.000*70, 35.000*70, 36.000*70]
amplitude= [26, 31, 29, 26, 27, 24, 24, 28, 24, 24, 28, 31, 24, 26, 55, 30, 73, 101, 168, 219, 448, 833, 1280, 1397, 1181, 1311,
            1715, 1975, 2003, 2034, 2178, 2180, 2182]
plt.plot(distance,amplitude, 'o')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, distance, amplitude,maxfev=100, bounds=((100, 10, 0), (200000, 200000, 200000)),p0=[2700, 3000, 1200])
print(popt)
plt.plot(distance, logistic(distance, *popt), 'r', label='logistic fit')
plt.show()
```

Comment: hi there! welcome to stack overflow. please check out the guide to [ask]. specifically - always make sure to look for other questions asking the same thing, and also always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback), pasted into your question as a code block, when asking about errors. thanks!

Comment: also, check to make sure all terms are defined in your code. what's `curve_fit`?

Comment: when I run your code, I don't get the same error. I do get a different error though - `x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (34,) and (33,)`, as `distance` and `amplitude` aren't the same length. Can you check your data to make sure you're not missing a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are few points on your code which had to be fixed.

1. distance and amplititle are not same size
2. both are list however inside you logistics definition you treat them as numpy array which you do vector operations
3. bounds value for k is wrong, it should be below 1 but you set minimum value to be 10, which make optimizing difficult
4. logistic definition you could add some safety measure for stability

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
def logistic(x, l, k, x1):
    e =  -k * (x - x1)
    e[ e > 30 ] = 30
    return l / (1 + np.exp(e))

distance= [1.000*70, 2.000*70, 3.000*70, 4.000*70, 5.000*70, 6.000*70, 7.000*70, 8.000*70,
           9.000*70, 11.00*70, 12.000*70, 13.000*70, 14.000*70, 15.000*70, 16.000*70,
           17.000*70, 18.000*70, 19.000*70, 21.000*70, 22.000*70, 23.000*70, 24.000*70, 25.000*70, 26.000*70,
           27.000*70, 28.000*70, 29.000*70, 30.000*70, 31.000*70, 32.000*70, 33.000*70,
           34.000*70, 35.000*70, 36.000*70]
amplitude= [26, 31, 29, 26, 27, 24, 24, 28, 24, 24, 28, 31, 24, 26, 55, 30, 73, 101, 168, 219, 448, 833, 1280, 1397, 1181, 1311,
            1715, 1975, 2003, 2034, 2178, 2180, 2182]
plt.plot(distance[1:], amplitude, 'o')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(logistic, np.array(distance[1:]), np.array(amplitude[:]),maxfev=100, bounds=((100, 0, 0), (3000, 1, 200000)),p0=[2700, 0.1, 1200])

print(popt)
plt.plot(distance, logistic(distance, *popt), 'r', label='logistic fit')

plt.show()
```

output:
[image]